# How to extend model class without passing data in constructor?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have model class:

```
class EduUnitModel {
    constructor(paren1tId: number,
    paren2tId: number,
    paren3tId: number,
    phone: string) {

    }
}
```

As sample, I need to extend `EduUnitModel` class by class:

```
class SchoolClassModel  {
    constructor(email: string) {

    }
}
```

I tried to do:

```
class EduUnitModel extends SchoolClassModel {
}
```

But it requires to send all properties to parent class in constructor.

How to extend one class by another to get class with properties from both classes?

**It helped me:**

```
class SchoolClassModel  {
    protected email: string | undefined;
}
```

Comment: I just need to create model then iterate all class properties and fill them

Comment: it sounds like your inheritance is reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, not in the constructor anyway. The reason being that once you define a constructor for your child, the parent constructor is no longer inherited. That is why a child constructor must invoke its parent constructor by calling `super()` and in your case, the parent requires an `email` param. What will you give to the parent constructor if `email` is not a part of your child?

```
class SchoolClassModel  {
    constructor(email: string) {

    }
}

class EduUnitModel extends SchoolClassModel {
    constructor(paren1tId: number,
    paren2tId: number,
    paren3tId: number,
    phone: string) {
        super(); // error because super requires 1 argument for email
    }
}
```

What you are hoping is that the argument `email` will be inherited into the constructor for `EdnUnitModel` by virtue of its child relationship, but that's not how inheritance works. Either the entire constructor is inherited from `SchoolClassModel` or none of it is and you have to explicitly call `super()` to invoke the parent constructor.

What you really want is to make your parent the most generic version of the class with optional constructor arguments. You can then use overloads to make the implementation simple.

```
class ParentModel {
    constructor(
    paren1tId: number,
    paren2tId: number,
    paren3tId: number,
    phone: string,
    );
    constructor(
        email: string
    );
    constructor(
    paren1tId?: number | string,
    paren2tId?: number,
    paren3tId?: number,
    phone?: string,
    email?: string
    ) {}
}

class SchoolClassModel extends ParentModel  {
    constructor(email: string) {
        super(email);
    }
}

class EduUnitModel extends ParentModel {
    constructor(paren1tId: number,
    paren2tId: number,
    paren3tId: number,
    phone: string) {
        super(paren1tId, paren2tId, paren3tId, phone);
    }
}
```

The parent class has typed every possible argument, with various overloaded versions. Then one implementation to handle every type of instantiation.